# Deriving Cube(a) from Cube(a) <-> a = a (Fitch)

Tags: computer-science, first-order-logic, fitch-proofs

I'm trying to prove something in Fitch and i'm stuck on one step, i have:

```
1.  Cube(a) <-> a = a
```

and i want to derive `2. Cube(a)` from that.

I know it's possible because i can use `Ana Con` on 2. and selecting 1. as premise and it says it's valid.
Is there anyone who can tell me how to do this without using `Ana Con`?

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ this one might be better place

Comment: Hmm ok, i was hesitating to put it there but decided not to in the end. Since i don't think i can *move* this, do i just delete it and open a new one there ?

Comment: @Andrey: cstheory is for **research level** questions in **theoretical** computer science. "Research-level" means, roughly, questions that might be discussed between two professors, or between graduate students working on Ph.D.'s, but not usually between a professor and the typical undergraduate student. Please don't redirect programming questions to us, they are off-topic on cstheory. Thanks.

Comment: ps: **non-research-level** theoretical questions should be redirected to [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) and not to cstheory.

Comment: All you would need to do on the next line is introduce the identity a=a. The line after that is biconditional elimination using those two lines which gives you Cube(a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I don't have a copy of Fitch and have never used it, so take this with a pinch of salt. But I'm pretty sure it's right.)

First get just "a=a" using =Intro. (You don't need any premises.) Then take that plus your 1. and apply <->Elim to get Cube(a).